# Getting a video's publish date - not upload date

Tags: youtube-data-api

Using Youtube's Data API V3, I am trying to get the date at which the video was published i.e. the date you see displayed here on the watch page:

[image]
<sub>(source: [gyazo.com](http://gyazo.com/0dbcc0eeacc0658c334189bc264f69f5.png))</sub>

Using the API, I have only been able to get the upload date which obviously doesn't get affected by scheduled releases.

At first I tried using [`playlistItems`](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/playlistItems) on the user's upload playlist. I soon found out that the published at date was actually the date this item was added to the playlist (which in this cases *is* the upload date)

I then turned to using [`videos`](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos) with the id fetched from the upload playlist. I assumed since I was no longer using data from within a parent list, the `publishedAt` would be the actual published at date, but no, still the upload date.

None of the parts including `status`, `snippet`, and `statistics` give the published date.

So... How do I get such a date?

Thank you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In [videos/list](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos), with `snippet` part, you now have `snippet.publishedAt`, which is the date on the watch page (and the one used to build the subscriptions feed).