# How to get a date part only from PublishedDate of YouTube API V3?

Tags: date, youtube, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I am using publishedDate variable from YouTube API but I just want to get the Date part instead of the whole part. How can I achieve that?

Comment: What language are you using to call the API?

Comment: What do you have so far?

Comment: @theduck I am using JavaScript/jQuery.

Comment: check this [SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26686642/getting-a-videos-publish-date-not-upload-date) if it can help you.